# Train random forest with caret using parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, r-caret

I would like to make use of the 20 CPU cores I have at hand to train random forests in R. My usual code using randomForest package would be this:

```
rf = randomForest(Pred~., train, ntree=100, importance=TRUE)
rf
```

So I train a forest with 100 trees using a factor `Pred` with 11 levels and a dataframe `train` with 74 numeric features and ~84k observations.

The idea was to speed this up by using caret with my code (derived from this [example](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/pml-randomForestPerformance.md)):

```
cluster <- makeCluster(19)
registerDoParallel(cluster)
trainctrl <- trainControl(method="none", number=1, allowParallel=TRUE)
fit <- train(Driver~., train, method="parRF", trControl=trainctrl, ntree=100)
stopCluster(cluster)
registerDoSEQ()
fit
```

I replaced `method=cv` from the example with `method=none` as I do want to train on the whole training set (see [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-81/topics/trainControl)). However I do not get an accuracy from `fit`, `fit$results` is empty. If I set `method=oob` an optimization of `mtry` is done, which also gives me accuracies.

**Is there a way to simply run the first code snippet in parallel using caret without any hyperparameter optimizations?**

Comment: I would advice to use  the `ranger` package. That runs parallel out of the box. `method = "ranger"` in caret.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that looks promissing on a first glimpse. I will look into that.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but you can try using the `doMC` package (it will likely not work in Windows though).

Sample Code:

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(doMC)

# Define the control
trControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
    number = 10,
    search = "grid")

# Define number of parallel instances you want
registerDoMC(8)

# define parameters for grid search
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(2: 5))

# train Random Forest model
rf_mtry <- train(TrainSet,yTrain,
    method = "rf",
    metric = "Accuracy",
    tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
    trControl = trControl,
    importance = TRUE,
    ntree = 300)

print(rf_mtry)
```

You can refer to [this post](https://chandramanitiwary.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/parallel-processing-of-random-forest-in-r-using-caret-and-domc-package/) as well.